# How to animate/playback handwriting drawings in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

Does any One have and idea how to playback handwriting drawings in iOS?

Comment: do you have the handwriting already ( if so in what format ) or the user is going to draw it in your app?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 6):

A good start would be Apple's SpeedSketch sample Swift Application, which captures user gestures to implement a simple drawing App:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeedSketch/Introduction/Intro.html

[image]

You can just store these gestures in an array and then play them back  at a speed of your choice. Voila, animated signature.

Comment: I know this is an old question. But i was hoping you could elaborate on how you actually "Call back" the gestures. I have them stored in an array. but calling them back to be displayed does not seem to be as straightforward as I anticipated.

Comment: @JulianSilvestri The code is all in the example I linked to. The specific code is here:

extension StrokeCGView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        UIColor.white.set()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        if let strokeCollection = strokeCollection {
            for stroke in strokeCollection.strokes {
                draw(stroke: stroke, in: rect)
            }
        }

        if let stroke = strokeToDraw {
            draw(stroke: stroke, in: rect)
        }
    }

}